# .NET Web API Record gets Deleted Upon Update using PUT Request

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, api

I have implemented an update functionality in my project using Repository pattern and DTOs.

Whenever I update a record, I get a success message but the record gets deleted !!

Here are few logs that might be useful:

```
      The 'RCJY' entity with key '{Id: 1002}' tracked by 'ApplicationDbContext' changed state from 'Unchanged' to 'Modified'.
dbug: 6/4/2023 13:55:26.384 CoreEventId.SaveChangesStarting[10004] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update) 
      SaveChanges starting for 'ApplicationDbContext'.
dbug: 6/4/2023 13:55:26.384 CoreEventId.DetectChangesStarting[10800] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking) 
      DetectChanges starting for 'ApplicationDbContext'.
dbug: 6/4/2023 13:55:26.387 CoreEventId.ForeignKeyChangeDetected[10803] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking) 
      The foreign key property 'RCJY.RootId' was detected as changed from '65' to '(null)' for entity with key '{Id: 1002}'.
dbug: 6/4/2023 13:55:26.400 CoreEventId.CascadeDeleteOrphan[10003] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update) 
      An entity of type 'RCJY' with key '{Id: 1002}' changed to 'Deleted' state due to severed required relationship to its parent entity of type 'Root'.
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PutMOD(int id, UpdateMODDto updateMODDto)
{
    // Check IDs equality
    if (id != updateMODDto.Id)
    {
        return BadRequest($"Not Found11 {id} {updateMODDto.Id}");
    }

    var entity = await _modRepository.GetAsync(id);

    if (entity == null)
    {
        throw new Exception($"MOH ID {id} not found");
    }

    _mapper.Map(updateMODDto, entity);

    try
    {
        await _modRepository.UpdateAsync(entity);
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
    {
        if (!await MODExists(id))
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
    return NoContent();
}
```

Repository:

```
public async Task UpdateAsync(T entity)
{
    _context.Update(entity);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

DTO:

```
public class UpdateMODDto : MODDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That you're having to trap a DbUpdateConcurrencyException seems suspicious.  Your code otherwise seems unremarkable; are you showing all of it that is relevant to your question?

Comment: Check in the database if the record was really deleted or something else

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't think it is from the DbUpdateConcurrencyException  since it is not reaching it and I am getting a No Content response which means it is reaching the end.

Comment: @Ricardo It gets deleted from the DB as well

Comment: try to enable logging and check how the sqls are being generated for this action

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/

Comment: Added few logs that might be useful